# DispatcherTimer stacking - UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, dispatchertimer

I'm currently working on a project in `UWP` and I have a `CommandBar` that I want to go from `Hidden` to `Compact` if the mouse moves. After five seconds (If the mouse dont move) the `CommandBar` should go back to `Hidden` again.

I dont get any errors, but when I move the mouse the `CommandBar` is going crazy and it's just flashing from `Hidden` to `Compact` when I move the mouse again. I think the problem is that the `OnMouseMovement` event is stacking upon itself.

This is my code for the mouse movement event:

```
public async void OnPointerMoved(object Sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CmdBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact;
    DispatcherTimer ButtonTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    ButtonTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    ButtonTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
    {
        CmdBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Hidden;
    };
    ButtonTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Well you create new timer on every mouse move, so there are hunders of timers running which will set mode to hidden (and mouse movement sets it to compact and adds more timers).

Comment: Do you know any solution for that? @Evk

Comment: Don't create new timer on every move. Instead have one timer and reset it every time mouse moves. Also don't forget to stop that timer when it ticks, otherwise it will tick every 5 seconds, and you need just once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a little test project to try it out and get you an answer, this is what I did :

```
private DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; }
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CmdBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Hidden;            
    Timer = new DispatcherTimer(){Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
    Timer.Tick += (sender, args) => { 
        CmdBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Hidden; 
        Timer.Stop();
    };

}

public async void OnPointerMoved(object Sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer.Stop();
    CmdBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact;
    Timer.Start();            
}
```

Basically as @Evk said, you are creating a new timer every move of your mouse. So I declared a property for the timer and stop it then restart it when your mouse move.

Comment: Worth stopping timer inside Tick also, otherwise it will tick every 5 seconds for no reason.

Comment: Okey, Thank you :) @Evk

Comment: @Evk Thanks, didn't think about that, I've edited the answer

Comment: @luddep Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it resolved your issue. Thanks !

Comment: @AntoineThity Oh Sorry, forgot that :D

Comment: @AntoineThiry Thanks :)